# в Google Chrome страница неправильно отображается

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файлы находятся не на локальном компе а на веб-хостинге. 
так,правильно(!) отображается страница в Firefox а в chrome вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Страница отображается без стилей? Где искать причину?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   }
#content {
    position:absolute;
    left:200px; top:50px; bottom: 0; right:0;
    height:800px;
    background:white;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
#sidebar {
    position:absolute;
    left:0; top:50px; bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;
 background:gray;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    left:200px; top:850px; right:0; bottom:0;
 background:gray;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
#nav{
  /* text-align:center; */
 /*  margin:0 auto; */
}
ul{ width:100%;
 height:50px;
 margin:0 auto;
 list-style:none;
 height:50px;
 background-color: #000; 
} 
li{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size:20px;
 position:relative;
}
li a{
 color:#fff;  
 display:block;
 height:50px;
 padding:0 10px;
 text-decoration:none;
 line-height:50px;
}
li a:hover{
 background:#000080;
}
.submenu{
 position:absolute;
 top:50px; 
 width:250px;
}
.submenu li{
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 background:red;
}
.submenu li a{
 line-height:50px;
 height:50px;
} 
.submenu li a:hover{
 background-color:#000;
}
li:hover .submenu li{
 display:block;
    z-index: 100; 
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Hello Word</title>
 </head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

<body>
  <div id="nav">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="">Main</a>
    <ul class="submenu"> 
      <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
     <li> <a href="#">Item2</a>
    <ul class="submenu"> 
      <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>  
     <li><a href="#">Item3</a>
    <ul class="submenu"> 
      <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>  
  <li><a href="#">Item4</a>
    <ul class="submenu"> 
      <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>  
     <li><a href="#">Contacts</a>
    <ul class="submenu"> 
      <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>   
   </ul>
  </div>
 
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
  <div id="content">
    <br />
    <form action="goods.php" method="post"> 
     good's name<br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="goods"<br/> 
    <input type="submit" name="btn_select" value="select">
    <input type="submit" name="btn_insert" value="insert">
    </form> 
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>

 <?php
 include "connect_db.php";
 ?>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: а у вас файл `styles.css` в одной папке с html файлом находится?

Comment: Евгений Шалаев, да конечно. И мозилла правильно отображает.

Comment: Папка public-html.

Comment: а консоль в `chrome` не ругается при загрузке страницы?

Comment: Возможно файл стилей в кэше старый. Посмотрите консоль 'Netzwerk'.

Comment: Евгений Шалаев,  Ilia Brykin очистил кэш и заработал но потом снова редактировал css файл но снова берёт старую из кэша. Снова очистил кэш и потом берёт уже из веб-сервера. Получается при каждом редактировании придётся  чистить кэш что-ли?

Comment: В Firefox всё в порядке- редактировал css,обновил и вижу адекватный результат.